# Not typical UnboundLocalError

Tags: python, django

Here is code:

```
def main(request):
    ..........
    div_list = soup.select('div')
    count = 0
    for div in div_list:
        count = count+1
    ..........
```

Error:

```
UnboundLocalError at /

local variable 'div_list' referenced before assignment
```

I can't get my head around it. Am I going insane? Where is the mistake?

Comment: What are the dots - more code - can you show? If they contain a  try except, for example and you try to access the variable outside of that - you would get this error - if there was a failure in the code.

Comment: Also, try using len(div_list) as opposed to a loop. 
Also, it has been a while since I used BSoup, but don't you use find_all() here? - disregard that second part if I am wrong :/